# What does pet mean here?

Tags: meaning

I saw a blog that says the blogger has a sick cat.

> Because of this, I have been giving her extra love and pets.

What does "pet" mean here? Is it a noun? I looked up its definition and it means pat only when it is a verb.

Comment: Stroking her fur and scalp is how folks pet their cat. Extra love and stroking. Pets (noun) for short. Also, you cannot use blogs as models of good writing. OMG.

Comment: oh my lord.....

Comment: Yes, it's an informal noun - 'an instance of petting' .

Answer (score 1):

Collins Dictionary has an entry for **pet** (near the last few pages, just after the section "Examples of 'pet' in a sentence" and before the section "COBUILD Collocations"), which means "affection".

The noun **affection** takes this definition in the same dictionary:

> 2. PLURAL NOUN [with poss]
>    Your affections are your feelings of love or fondness for someone.

Comment: Not found in https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pet ?

Comment: It's near the end, just after the section "Examples of 'pet' in a sentence" and before the section "COBUILD Collocations".